# Sencha Touch 2 carousel orientation change

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am having issues in a Sencha Touch 2 / Phonegap application managing orientation changes in a `carousel` that shows a list of [ImageViewer](https://github.com/SunboX/ST2_ImageViewer) items.

When I open up `carousel` everything is all right. If I change orientation of the device (both in Chrome through Ripple plugin or on an iPhone4S) the layout adapt itself correctly.

Problem arises when after changing orientation I swipe to the next image. That has been preloaded and sits in a container dimensioned for the preceding orientation so the layout is messed up.

[image] [image]

Note that if I keep swiping to the next image layout is correct again, since my `carousel` only preload a single image.

I managed to intercept the `changeorientation` event on `Ext.Viewport` to take an action on carousel to fix this behaviour, I tried to trigger the resize event both on the carousel and on the ImageViewer but with no success. I also tried to trigger the `changeorientation` event on the `Ext.Viewport` each time the activeItem of carousel changes but that didn't work either. Do you have any ideas of what could be done to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by iterating through every item in the carousel and calling the resize() method on the ImageViewer items after the orientationchange is fired on the Viewport.  My function looks like this:

```
handleOrientationChange: function(viewport, orientation, width, height){
    var items = this.getItems();
    for (var i=0;i<items.getCount();i++){
        var obj = items.getAt(i);
        if (obj instanceof Ext.view.ux.ImageViewer){
            console.log("Resize");
            obj.resize();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to verify that the item is an Imageviewer.  The carousel indicator also gets returned in the ItemCollection.

I'm not 100% sure this is the most efficient way, but it does work.

Comment: Thank you very much @GerryL, I did try to resize the ImageViewers but my solution didn't work because of an error in how I was iterating the ItemCollection returned by getItems().

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your .css file

```
.my-carousel-item{background:url(images/loading.png) no-repeat center center}@media screen and (orientation: portrait){.my-carousel-item-img{background-size:100% auto}}@media screen and (orientation: landscape){.my-carousel-item-img{background-size:auto 100%}}.x-portrait .my-carousel-item-img{background-size:100% auto}.x-landscape .my-carousel-item-img{background-size:auto 100%}.my-carousel-item-img{background-position:center center}.x-carousel-indicator>*{background-color:orange !important;opacity:0.4}.x-carousel-indicator>.x-carousel-indicator-active{opacity:1}
```